# mod user_dir and wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

I am trying to setup a public_html/django_app folder, where all urls like ~/{username}/django would execute the .wsgi file located there.

The idea is to checkout our project inside of the django folder, and have it work for everyone without further apache config.

Right now, our project is running in /var/www/project_name, but I would like every user to be able to checkout the project in their own folder /home/{username}/public_html/django_app, and I don't want them to edit any apache config.

So I guess the question is, what is the best way / location to do this in the apache configuration. I would like to avoid creating VirtualHosts for everyone, just to change

```
WSGIScriptAlias django_app/ /home/{username}/django_app/core.wsgi
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

> WSGIScriptAliasMatch
>   ^/~([^/]+)/django_app
>   /home/$1/public_html/django_app/core.wsgi